# Spring Boot 2.3.0 buildpack builds image with creation date 40 years ago

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, buildpack

I've tried to use buildpack in a maven project with Spring Boot 2.3.0 running:

```
mvn spring-boot:build-image
```

Image was created just fine, but I see the following info for it:

```
REPOSITORY                                    TAG                     IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/builder              base-platform-api-0.3   daceb4f909b7        40 years ago        690MB
myimage                                       master                  a482a4a34379        40 years ago        285MB
```

Why does it say the image (along with the builder) was created 40 years ago?

Comment: Found this in buildpacks repo: https://github.com/buildpacks/rfcs/pull/50/files with link to https://reproducible-builds.org/docs/source-date-epoch/ . Still not sure how it's related to building an image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is by design. In order to create reproducible builds (i.e. so that layers can be reused) the buildpack must create layers with a fixed time stamp. Otherwise, you wouldn’t be able to reuse the layers you created in previous builds because they would have different time stamps.

Comment: Aren't layers reused based on hash? I don't understand really what it has to do with timestamp and why real one couldn't be specified. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The timestamp of a file changes the hash. Many of the next-gen container builders (buildpacks, jib, ko) use fixed, not-quite-zero timestamp values to guarantee image reproducibility

Comment: This is anything but "expected". It seems the builders couldn't figure out how to create effective hash, and instead resorted on a fake timestamp.

Comment: This is what many other tools do (ko, jib, etc). Explained here: https://medium.com/buildpacks/time-travel-with-pack-e0efd8bf05db

Comment: While it is true that other tools also offer this option, they of course also offer the option to use the current time, because this is what most people will expect. When using Quarkus out of the box (which uses jib), we get the expected current timestamp. When replacing docker builder with jib in spring boot, we may set creation time to USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and get the desired result. How about supporting that as well in buildpack?

Comment: I agree with malamut - it certainly does seem like what anyone would expect - why should a hash change with the timestamp of a file - taking the date into account doens't seem like a sound design for a hash...

Comment: I probably should have used a better word. I've changed this to "by design"

Comment: Pack already supports this feature: `--creation-time string`. Accepted values are Unix timestamps (e.g., '1641013200'), or 'now'

-- source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28798#issuecomment-1248078882

Comment: Any updates on this? Is it possible to alter that behaviour so that the correct timestamp is used?

Comment: I'm trying a lot of things, even adding tasks.named("bootBuildImage") {
    def currentDate = new Date().getTime()
    environment['SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH'] = currentDate.toString()
}
but the image is still created in 1980.

Answer (score 6):

In the new version you can set it.
Hier is the gradle example

```
bootBuildImage {
      imageName = "docker.io/ringo"
      createdDate = "now"
}
```

Comment: Do you have the documentation link for this?

Comment: is only in the new 3.1.0 RC 1 version 

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.1.0-RC1-Release-Notes

Comment: yep, thats was I saw :D thank you

Comment: version 3.1.0 is out :)

Answer (score 1):

For maven projects, add the following configurations to your POM file

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <image>
         <name>${project.artifactId}:latest</name>
            <env>
               <BP_JVM_VERSION>21.*</BP_JVM_VERSION>
            </env>
            <createdDate>${maven.build.timestamp}</createdDate>
      </image>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```