# Use Paketo.io / CloudNativeBuildpacks (CNB) in GitLab CI with Kubernetes executor & unprivileged Runners (without pack CLI & docker)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, paketo

We want to use [Paketo.io](https://paketo.io) / [CloudNativeBuildpacks (CNB)](https://buildpacks.io) [GitLab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/) in the most simple way. Our GitLab setup uses an AWS EKS cluster with unprivileged GitLab CI Runners leveraging [the Kubernetes executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html). We also **don't want to introduce security risks** by [using Docker in our builds](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#using-docker-in-your-builds). So we don't have our host’s `/var/run/docker.sock` exposed nor want to use `docker:dind`.

We found some guides on how to use Paketo with GitLab CI like this https://tanzu.vmware.com/developer/guides/gitlab-ci-cd-cnb/ . But as described beneath the headline `Use Cloud Native Buildpacks with GitLab in GitLab Build Job WITHOUT Using the GitLab Build Template`, the approach relies on Docker and pack CLI. We tried to resemble this in our `.gitlab-ci.yml` which looks like this:

```
image: docker:20.10.9

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - |
    echo "install pack CLI (see https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/pack/)"
    apk add --no-cache curl
    (curl -sSL "https://github.com/buildpacks/pack/releases/download/v0.21.1/pack-v0.21.1-linux.tgz" | tar -C /usr/local/bin/ --no-same-owner -xzv pack)

build-image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - pack --version
    - >
      pack build $REGISTRY_GROUP_PROJECT/$CI_PROJECT_NAME:latest
      --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base
      --path .
```

But as outlined our setup does not support docker and we end up with the following error inside our logs:

```
...
$ echo "install pack CLI (see https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/pack/)" # collapsed multi-line command
install pack CLI (see https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/pack/)
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/4) Installing brotli-libs (1.0.9-r5)
(2/4) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.43.0-r0)
(3/4) Installing libcurl (7.79.1-r0)
(4/4) Installing curl (7.79.1-r0)
Executing busybox-1.33.1-r3.trigger
OK: 12 MiB in 26 packages
pack
$ pack --version
0.21.1+git-e09e397.build-2823
$ pack build $REGISTRY_GROUP_PROJECT/$CI_PROJECT_NAME:latest --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base --path .
ERROR: failed to build: failed to fetch builder image 'index.docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:base': Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Any idea on how to use Paketo Buildpacks with GitLab CI without having Docker present inside our GitLab Kubernetes runners (which seems to be kind of a best practice)? We also don't want our setup to become to complex - e.g. by adding [kpack](https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/kpack/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TLDR;

Use the Buildpack's lifecycle directly inside your `.gitlab-ci.yml` [here's a fully working example](https://gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml)):

```
image: paketobuildpacks/builder

stages:
  - build

# We somehow need to access GitLab Container Registry with the Paketo lifecycle
# So we simply create ~/.docker/config.json as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41710291/4964553
before_script:
  - mkdir ~/.docker
  - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_JOB_TOKEN\"}}}" >> ~/.docker/config.json

build-image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - /cnb/lifecycle/creator -app=. $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
```

---

### The details: "using the lifecycle directly"

There are ongoing discussions about this topic. Especially have a look into https://github.com/buildpacks/pack/issues/564 and https://github.com/buildpacks/pack/issues/413#issuecomment-565165832. As stated there:

> If you're looking to build images in CI (not locally), I'd encourage
> you to use the lifecycle directly for that, so that you don't need
> Docker. Here's an example:

The link to the example is broken, but it refers to the [Tekton](https://tekton.dev/) implementation on [how to use buildpacks in a Kubernetes environment](https://github.com/tektoncd/catalog/blob/main/task/buildpacks/0.3/buildpacks.yaml). Here we can get a first glue about what Stephen Levine referred to as `"to use the lifecycle directly"`. Inside it the crucial point is the usage of `command: ["/cnb/lifecycle/creator"]`. **So this is the lifecycle everyone is talking about!** And there's good documentaion about this command that could be found [in this CNB RFC](https://github.com/buildpacks/rfcs/blob/main/text/0026-lifecycle-all.md#usage).

### Choosing a good image: paketobuildpacks/builder:base

So how to develop a working `.gitlab-ci.yml`? Let's start simple. Digging [into the Tekton implementation](https://github.com/tektoncd/catalog/blob/main/task/buildpacks/0.3/buildpacks.yaml) you'll see that the lifecycle command is executed inside an environment defined in `BUILDER_IMAGE`, which itself is documented as `The image on which builds will run (must include lifecycle and compatible buildpacks).` That sound's familiar! Can't we simply pick the builder image `paketobuildpacks/builder:base` from our pack CLI command? Let's try this locally on our workstation before commiting to much noise into our GitLab. Choose a project you want to build (I created a example Spring Boot app if you'd like at [gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot](https://gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot) you can clone) and run:

```
docker run --rm -it -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app paketobuildpacks/builder bash
```

Now inside the `paketobuildpacks/builder` image powered container try to run the Paketo lifecycle directly with:

```
/cnb/lifecycle/creator -app=. microservice-api-spring-boot:latest
```

I only used the `-app` parameter of [the many possible parameters for the `creator` command](https://github.com/buildpacks/rfcs/blob/main/text/0026-lifecycle-all.md#usage), since most of them have quite good defaults. But as the default app directory path is not the default `/workspace` - but the current directory, I configured it. Also we need to define an `<image-name>` at the end, which will simply be used as the resulting container image name.

### The first .gitlab-ci.yml

Both commands did work at my local workstation, so let's finally create a `.gitlab-ci.yml` using this approach ([here's a fully working example `.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot/-/blob/add-gitlab-ci/.gitlab-ci.yml)):

```
image: paketobuildpacks/builder

stages:
  - build

build-image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - /cnb/lifecycle/creator -app=. $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
```

### docker login without docker

As we don't have `docker` available inside our Kubernetes Runners, we can't [login into GitLab Container Registry as described in the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/#authenticate-by-using-gitlab-cicd). So the following error occured to me using this first approach:

```
===> ANALYZING
ERROR: failed to get previous image: connect to repo store "gitlab.yourcompanyhere.cloud:4567/yourgroup/microservice-api-spring-boot:latest": GET https://gitlab.yourcompanyhere.cloud/jwt/auth?scope=repository%3Ayourgroup%2Fmicroservice-api-spring-boot%3Apull&service=container_registry: DENIED: access forbidden
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Using the approach [described in this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46422186/4964553) fixed the problem. We need to create a `~/.docker/config.json` containing the GitLab Container Registry login information - and then [the Paketo build will pick them up, as stated in the docs](https://github.com/buildpacks/spec/blob/main/platform.md#registry-authentication):

> If `CNB_REGISTRY_AUTH` is unset and a docker config.json file is
> present, the lifecycle SHOULD use the contents of this file to
> authenticate with any matching registry.

Inside our `.gitlab-ci.yml` this could look like:

```
# We somehow need to access GitLab Container Registry with the Paketo lifecycle
# So we simply create ~/.docker/config.json as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41710291/4964553
before_script:
  - mkdir ~/.docker
  - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_JOB_TOKEN\"}}}" >> ~/.docker/config.json
```

### Our final .gitlab-ci.yml

As we're using the `image: paketobuildpacks/builder` at the top of our `.gitlab-ci.yml`, we can now leverage the lifecycle directly. Which is what we wanted to do in the first place. Only remember to use the correct GitLab CI variables to describe your `<image-name>` like this:

```
/cnb/lifecycle/creator -app=. $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
```

Otherwise the Buildpack process analyser step will break and it finally won't get pushed to the GitLab Container Registry. So finally our `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this ([here's the fully working example](https://gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml)):

```
image: paketobuildpacks/builder

stages:
  - build

# We somehow need to access GitLab Container Registry with the Paketo lifecycle
# So we simply create ~/.docker/config.json as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41710291/4964553
before_script:
  - mkdir ~/.docker
  - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_JOB_TOKEN\"}}}" >> ~/.docker/config.json

build-image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - /cnb/lifecycle/creator -app=. $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
```

Our builds should now run successfully using Paketo/Buildpacks without pack CLI and Docker:

[image]

See [the full log of the example project here](https://gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot/-/jobs/1679982122).

Comment: can you enhance your answer and example to provide custom bindings ? Most real-world usecases need apm agents to be added to the OCI image. I am trying to figure out how that is possible using the `cnb/lifecycle/creator`

Comment: https://github.com/buildpacks/rfcs/blob/main/text/0026-lifecycle-all.md#usage

Comment: Looking in the Container Registry, do you know why the Published Date is not accurate?  How to fix it?

Comment: @Sully yeah per default the image dates are set to `40 years ago` :) This has some reasons [because of reproducible builds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62866908/4964553). Otherwise layer reusage wouldn't be possible. So its by design.

Comment: @jonashackt, thank you for the response.  I found a way to resolve it and added it as an answer here.  So is adding the approach in my answer forces to rebuild all layers?

Comment: Great question, but yeah I guess it would rebuild all layers. But not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @jonashackt answer, I had an issue with the "**Published Date**" set to January 1, 1980
(https://github.com/buildpacks/spec/pull/292)

To fix it I had to set `SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH` to unix epoch and `CNB_PLATFORM_API` to 0.9 or above

```
build-image:
  stage: build
  image: paketobuildpacks/builder
  variables:
    CNB_PLATFORM_API: "0.9"
  before_script:
    - export SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=`date "+%s"`
    - mkdir ~/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_JOB_TOKEN\"}}}" >> ~/.docker/config.json
  script:
    - /cnb/lifecycle/creator -app=. $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
```